# Moving lines in terminal / or reading their content - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I need a custom shell running on a separate thread. For example:

`shell> some command`

There are no issues with user input. The only thing that bothers me - is how additional messages are displayed in the console.
Instead of printing the message out before the input line, it prints it afterward. For example, if a new client connects to my server, it prints out "Client connected" as needed, but not where needed

`shell> some commandClient connected!`

I tried rewriting the line and printing the shell prefix again:

```
print("\rClient connected!")
print("shell>")
```

but then it lets me delete the exact amount of characters as I typed. For example, if I typed in the console "ls":

```
Client connected!
shel-- # <-- it let's me delete these characters
```

Is there a way to add a new blank line before the current one without erasing anything?
Or maybe I can read what the user has typed at this moment, to rewrite the line, but print it back how it was later?